# ListBox/Listview with windows icons

Tags: c#, windows, listview, icons

I'm looking to have a scrollable list box that could have any number of items. Those items when ran could succeed or fail. So I want to have a success icon, a fail icon, and optionally a loading gif. For the first two parts I know windows has the exact icons I'm looking for. I want to know is there any control made for a task like this?

On a similar note i think i could get a listview to do what i want but I'm not sure where i would get those icons. Plus I would rather use something similar to the messagebox icon enum then have a icon resx

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of projects which give you a ListView with icons, so you could just adapt one of those.

One example is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097752/55487), and another in [this CodeProject entry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4012/C-List-View-v).

Note that you'd need to update the images as the status of each item changes.